# Error compiling g2o for RGBD-Slam

Tags: slam, g2o, macos, rgbd-slam, macos-lion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to compile [g2o](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=g2o) for rgbd-slam, but it fails with:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../../../lib/libg2o_types_icp.dylib
[ 84%] Built target types_icp
Scanning dependencies of target solver_pcg
[ 86%] Building CXX object g2o/solvers/pcg/CMakeFiles/solver_pcg.dir/solver_pcg.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../../../lib/libg2o_solver_pcg.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "std::set<g2o::HyperGraph::Edge*, std::less<g2o::HyperGraph::Edge*>, std::allocator<g2o::HyperGraph::Edge*> >::size() const", referenced from:
  g2o::BlockSolver<g2o::BlockSolverTraits<7, 3> >::solve() in solver_pcg.cpp.o
  g2o::BlockSolver<g2o::BlockSolverTraits<6, 3> >::solve() in solver_pcg.cpp.o
  g2o::BlockSolver<g2o::BlockSolverTraits<3, 2> >::solve() in solver_pcg.cpp.o
  g2o::BlockSolver<g2o::BlockSolverTraits<-1, -1> >::solve() in solver_pcg.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [../lib/libg2o_solver_pcg.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [g2o/solvers/pcg/CMakeFiles/solver_pcg.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

ROS Fuerte on OSX 10.7.3

What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34006/error-compiling-g2o-for-rgbd-slam/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2012-05-15**:
Make sure the libg2o_solver_pcg.dylib library has x86_64 symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is broke and doesn't work on OSX

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1